# ImportError: No module named numjy

Tags: numpy, jython, importerror, attributeerror, jython-music

I am trying to import the **numjy** package, as described in the "How to fix numpy importerror in JythonMusic" topic but am getting the "ImportError: No module named numjy" message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XI-USER\JythonMusic\untitled 1", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numjy
```

I downloaded the numjy-master.zip [here](https://github.com/Yaqiang/numjy), and put the numjy-master folder in my main JythonMusic folder. I also tried putting the numjy folder *within* the numjy-master folder (so leaving out the src folder, and the pom.xml file) in the main JythonMusic folder with the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XI-USER\JythonMusic\untitled 1", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'arrange'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming numjy has a similar API to numpy, the second error arises from `arrange` needing to be `arange` (only 1 "r" character)

Answer (score 0):

Moving "the numjy folder within the numjy-master folder (so leaving out the src folder, and the pom.xml file) in the main JythonMusic folder" was **the right thing to do**.

**You are now using numjy**.

(The second error was just a typo - as pointed out by Matt Eding above.)

Comment: Dear Bill and Matt,
Thank you! It works now, together with plotjy - but only if I save the project in the main JythonMusic folder.